# Can someone verify my direct proof that if $A$ is a subset of $B$, $A\cup B = B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

[image]

I am trying to use a direct proof to do this problem.

Here is my book's explanation/section on direct proof
[image]

Here is my work so far[image]

I used this property of sets(from  https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture09-filled.pdf)
[image]

Basically that two sets are equal if they are subsets of each other.

I know that for a direct proof, I am trying to prove p -> q, or in this case, if A is a subset of B, then the union of A and B is equal to B.  My first step was assuming that  A is a subset of B meaning that if x is in A, x is also in B. Because I have an implication involving two propositions, I used the law of implication to convert p -> q into ~p v q.

My initial assumption ends up being X is not in A or x is in B.(assumption). I first tried showing that $A\cup B$ is a subset of B. To do this, I used the definition of $A\cup B$ to say that if X is a member of $A\cup B$, either X is in A or X is in B. From our initial assumption(X is not in A or X is in B), if X is in A, then X has to be in B(first condition isn't met, second has to be met). In the other case if X is in B, then X is in B. So In either case of the Union possibility, X ends up being a member of B. After this, I have shown that B is a subset of $A\cup B$.

My next step was to show that B is a subset of $A\cup B$. Or another way of saying it, if X is a member of B, then it is a member of $A\cup B$. By definition of union, if X is a member of $A\cup B$,  is either in A or in B. From that, my next logical step was saying that if X is a member of B, it is also a member of $A\cup B$  because it meets the second condition in the conjunction, in B.  I can now conclude that  $A\cup B$ is a subset of B.

Because I have shown that if A is a subset of B,  $A\cup B$  is a subset of B and B is a subset of $A\cup B$. By definition of equality of sets, $A\cup B$ is equal to B.

Does everything look logically coherent/organized? Is there any part I can rephrase to make it more understandable?

Comment: when you said “second condition in the conjunction” you meant “second condition in the *disjunction*”.  But yes, this is correct. I suggest that you copy it over more carefully, this time thinking ahead of time how you are going to lay it out on the page, so that you don't hand in a cluttered sheet with a lot of eraser marks.

Comment: I agree with Joffan's suggestion below that converting $p\to q$ to $\lnot p \lor q$ has only made things more complicated.  You had to do an analysis of two  cases, one of which ended with “if X is in A, then X has to be in B(first condition isn't met, second has to be met).”. But if you had left the condition as “If $x$ is in $A$, then $x$ is in $B$” you wouldn't have needed to justify this, bause it was exactly what you wanted to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it something like this.

> We want to show $A\cup B = B$.  There are two parts:
>
> 1. First, we want to show $B\subseteq A\cup B$.  Assume $x\in B$. Then certainly $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, so we are done.
> 2. Now we show $A\cup B\subseteq B$.  Assume $x\in A\cup B$; we want to show $x\in B$.  Since $x\in A\cup B$,  either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. if  the latter case holds we are already done.  In the former case we can conclude that $x\in B$ because of the hypothesis that $A\subseteq B$.

I think this is not only easier to follow than a completely symbolic proof, and less prone to dumb errors, but it is also shorter.  (Also, it is easier for the grader to see that you understand what is going on.)

Comment: yeah i shouldn't have converted p→q to ¬p∨q

Comment: @committedandroider I should also have said that I think your proof is correct, and if I had been grading it I would have given it full marks.

Comment: Always better to make it simpler though.

Answer (score 4):

Symbolically:

$\qquad A\cup B = B 
\\\equiv \Big\{ x\mid(x \in A\vee x\in B) \leftrightarrow x\in B \Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big((x\in A\vee x\in B)\to x\in B\big) \wedge \big(x\in B\to (x\in B\vee x\in A)\big)\Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big((x\in A\vee x\in B)\to x\in B\big) \wedge \top\Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big((x\in A\vee x\in B)\to x\in B\big) \Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big(x\in A\to x\in B\big)\wedge \big(x\in B \to x\in B\big)\Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big(x\in A\to x\in B\big)\wedge \top\Big\}
\\ \equiv \Big\{ x \mid \big(x\in A\to x\in B\big)\Big\}
\\ \equiv A\subseteq B
$

Using this as a guideline we obtain a direct proof.

- Assuming $A \subseteq B$ then $A\cup B \subseteq B$ because every element in $A$ is in $B$ (from the assumption) and every element in $B$ is in $B$ (clearly), so every element in the union of the two must be in $B$.

  - Additionally $A\cup B \supseteq B$ because every element in $B$ is in the union $A\cup B$ by definition.
  - This means that $A\cup B = B$ when we assume that $A\subseteq B$.
- Assuming that $A\cup B = B$ then every element in $A$, being an element of the union, is an element of $B$, and hence we have $A\subseteq B$ when we assume $A\cup B = B$.

We conclude that $A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to $A\cup B = B$

Comment: Yeah this is so much more concise than mine

Comment: And T is used to represent a tautology right, like no matter what value of X you pass into (x∈B→(x∈B∨x∈A)), the conditional statement will always evaluate to true

Comment: When you work down the steps to A⊆B, does that symbolically mean  (x∈A∨x∈B)↔x∈B can be broken down to saying that, that they are logically equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Looks reasonable. Your handwritten version doesn't exactly explain 
$$\begin{align}
x\in A \lor x \in B \\
\text{ and ... }x\not\in A \land x \in B \\
\text{ ... to ...}\\ 
x \in B\\
\end{align}$$
but you do explain that in the text here. I think I would have kept the implication $x\in A \implies x \in B $ and gone through like this:
$$\begin{align}
x\in A \lor x \in B \\
\implies x\in B \lor x \in B \\
\implies x \in B\\
\end{align}$$

and you could be briefer inferring that $B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: and ⟹x∈B∨x∈B comes from the initial assumption that A is a subset of B?

Comment: @committedandroider correct, we're using that assumption. Notice we're flowing the same direction on the implication arrows; we couldn't go backwards on that step.